# Dict from two lists including multiple values for keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a possibility to create a dict from two lists with same key occurring multiple times **without** iterating over the whole dataset?

Minimal example:

```py
keys = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

# hoped for result:
dictionary = dict(???)
dictionary = {1 : [1,8], 2:[2,4], 3:[3,5], 4:[6], 5:[7]}
```

When using `zip` the key-value-pair is inserted overwriting the old one:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(keys,values))
dictionary = {1: 8, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 5: 7}
```

I would be happy with a Multidict as well.

Comment: See the first defaultdict example in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: Sorry, I meant without explicitly iterating over the dataset. I really like the `zip` method due to it's simplicity

Comment: Zip the lists, `group` the resulting pairs, and build your `dict` from the sequence of groups.

Comment: @LeoE, the main question is "Why do need that at all?", as you realize that `zip` is not enough and at least one some traversal is required

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It is less of a question, why I need it, it is more of a question, if anybody knows a way to do it. I think we are all here to learn new things and today I found out, that there is no simple, fast and readable(!) way to write this code. This is a result for me as well and I learned something

Comment: @LeoE, "*there is no simple, fast and readable(!) way*" - and that's wrong conclusion. You've already been suggested with `defaultdict`. Moreover, in Python - loop is not equal to "unreadable code"

Comment: It's overkill but you can use `itertools.groupby` + `operator.itemgetter` if you first `zip` and then `sort`. For example: `{k: list(map(itemgetter(1), v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(keys, values)), itemgetter(0))}`. That being said, the simple loop is the preferred method. Furthermore there is no way to avoid iterating - even `zip` iterates.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest and I'm absolutely okay with that, but it can always be the case, that I just haven't got a clue about some zip mechanics/ itertools etc that someone else might have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach that doesn't require 2 for loops

```
h = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    h[k].append(v)

print(h)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [1, 8], 2: [2, 4], 3: [3, 5], 4: [6], 5: [7]})

print(dict(h))
# {1: [1, 8], 2: [2, 4], 3: [3, 5], 4: [6], 5: [7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only one-liner I could do.

```
dictionary = {k: [values[i] for i in [j for j, x in enumerate(keys) if x == k]] for k in set(keys)}
```

It is far from readable. Remember that clear code is always better than pseudo-clever code ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that I think is easy to follow logically. Unfortunately it does not use `zip` like you would prefer, nor does it avoid iterating, because a task like this has to involve iterating In some form.

```
# Your data
keys = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

# Make result dict
result = {}
for x in range(1, max(keys)+1):
    result[x] = []

# Populate result dict
for index, num in enumerate(keys):
    result[num].append(values[index])

# Print result
print(result)
```

If you know the range of values in the `keys` array, you could make this faster by providing the `results` dictionary as a literal with integer keys and empty list values.